# SVN repo not found after upgrading centos 6.4 to 6.5

Tags: centos, svn

I installed svn client centos 6.4 but it was not working and throwing an error and not checking out the project. I googled it around and find a blog stating to upgrade centos.

So i did upgrade and svn still didnt work out.

Then after I re-installed and tried to install again. But now a strange thing happening. 
on command: yum install svn

it says that no package svn available. Please help me get out of it.
Any help will be appreciated....

Thanks

Comment: The name of the package is `subversion`.

Comment: yes buddy, but it can be installed through svn command. Actually all repos got deleted but i dont when. Now everything is working fine. I have got them from a friend of mine. By the way, Thanks for paying the attention.